# How to capture Log4net Appender errors when Log4net Debugging turned off

Tags: .net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using `Log4net`.  I recently decided to add a trace listener to a file to my configuration, to capture any errors generated by `Log4net` itself. (The 
[Log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) includes an example configuration for this.)

(I'm talking about cases when `Log4net` generates an error message of its own, due to being unable to do its job.  I'm not talking about configuring it to log *application* errors.)

While testing this, I messed around with my `Log4net` configuration in a test project so as to force `Log4net` or `ADO.Net Appender` errors, to verify they were handled correctly by the Trace Listener setup.

What I have found suggests that intrinsic `Log4net` errors will be written to the trace listener, even if `Log4net` debugging is turned off.  *This is what I want*.

Here's an example error I generated by tweaking the type name of a `Log4net.Layout` in the `app.config` to refer to a non-existent type.  This was the only entry in the Trace Listener file, which is what I wanted.

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayoutXX]
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayoutXX]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies
  at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
  at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
  at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
log4net:ERROR Failed to create object to set param: layout
```

But, I also found that if the error is in an external system (such as, in the example below, a SQL Server error), the error *will only appear in the trace listener file if `Log4net` debugging is turned ON*.  Which means that it's surrounded by a great deal of internal housekeeping information.

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@log_date".
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
  at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
ClientConnectionId:8ddb2758-4adc-495e-af8b-c16e0acc937a
Error Number:137,State:2,Class:15
```

I don't want to run with debugging turned on all the time, just to catch this kind of error.  This app runs something like 70 times a day and generates 25KB of debug trace listener output per run, just from internal housekeeping.  I don't want to have to wade through megabytes of noise to find the one signal.

So, my questions:

1. Is it possible to capture errors that are fatal to an `Appender` in the trace listener, without having `Log4net` debugging turned on?
2. Is this behavior by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.  A nice, elegant one.

All Appender classes in `Log4net` have a public property called `ErrorHandler`.  By default, this is set to an instance of a class called `OnlyOnceErrorHandler`, that will log an error to the Debug feed (if enabled) and then stop reporting errors.

But you can override this, through configuration:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\logfile.txt" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="50GB" />
      <errorHandler type="MyTraceLoggingErrorHandler, MyAssembly" />
```

The `ErrorHandler` implements the very simple interface `IErrorHandler`, and can do whatever you want it to do.

In my case, I simply had it write the messages and exceptions it received to the `TraceListener`:

```
Trace.WriteLine(message);
Trace.WriteLine(errorCode);
Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
Trace.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
```

And that solved my problem.